# Problems with WP_List_Table and hooks

Tags: admin, hooks, wp-list-table

I'd like to use the WP_List_Table in my plugin, so I followed the guide of [WP-Engineer](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) to create the WP_List_Table. His version of the code is available on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/Latz/7f923479a4ed135e35b2

As I mentioned, the WP_List_Table works for me, when I display it with
$myListTable->display();

But I also want to have this typical Settings Page, where I can change the settings for the WP_List_Table like the columns shown in the table.

The guide uses the add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_add_menu_items' ); hook. But this somehow does not work for me. I just tried to use the full code from git mentioned above but I'm getting no table and no settings screen.

Can someone help me with it?